# How to find the Nearest Neighbor in sentences (names)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I have a Table like this one bellow:

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>CHILD </th><th>FATHER </th><th>MOTHER</th></tr><tr><td>Jhon Morris </td><td>David Morris </td><td>Alicia Morris</td></tr><tr><td>Charles Reed </td><td>George Reed </td><td>Megan Reed</td></tr><tr><td>Daniel Morris </td><td>David Morris </td><td>Alicia Morris</td></tr><tr><td>Anthony Morris </td><td>Ronald Morris </td><td>Mary Morris</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

and I need to get the most similiar items, example:
Input:

> John Morris

Return:

> Most similar is Daniel Morris' (his brother)
>
> Second most similar is Anthony Morris (his cousin)

How can I do this?

Comment: It's unclear if you are looking for similarity from the standpoint of linguistics, genetics, or your data structure.  Do you have example code to give an idea of the output you are looking for?